# how can on define an operation over the most recent X days in a pandas frame?

Tags: pandas

Say I have a pandas DataFrame with sales data for a clothes store chain:

```
model     day          shop   amount sold    price
polo      01-01-2006   B7     3              42.45
polo      01-01-2006   C8     4              41.45
polo      02-01-2006   C8     4              41.43
polo      03-01-2006   B8     1              41.45
sweater   01-01-2006   B7     2              71.57
sweater   02-01-2006   B7     2              71.56
```

I would like to compute the total revenue per model in the preceding 60 days across all shops. So, for the example table above, the answer should be something that for `polo` contains the time series:

```
01-01-2006: 0
02-01-2006: 3*42.45 + 4*41.45
03-01-2006: 3*42.45 + 4*41.45 + 4*41.43
```

and for `sweater` contains the data

```
01-01-2006: 0
02-01-2006: 2*71.57
```

The table is large (over 10^8 rows) so computationally efficient answers are preferred. I'm flexible as to whether it's the past 60 calendar days or the past 60 days for which there's any data available, whichever is easiest to implement.

I presume I need to start grouping by model first, then by day, but it's not clear how to create a rolling window over a certain number of days, regardless of how many shops have a data row for that day. Alternatively I've considered adding columns `start_date` and `end_date` for the desired interval, but it's then not clear how to tell the group_by query that it should sum over everything where day is between those two. So any help would be welcome

Comment: Why does your example show 0 as the result for date 01-01-2006?

Comment: @TobyPetty because the 60 preceding days are 02-11-2005 to 31-12-2005, which have no sales

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# First, make sure that the `day` column is of type Timestamp, not string:
df['day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['day'])

# Add a revenue column
df['revenue'] = df['amount_sold'] * df['price']

# Sum revenue by model and day
# There is some index manipulation to prepare for the next command
tmp = df.groupby(['model', 'day'])['revenue'].sum().reset_index(level=0)

# For each model, calculate the previous 60 day revenue, excluding the ending day
# (hence closed on left but not right)
result = tmp.groupby('model').apply(lambda g: g.rolling('61D', closed='left').sum()).fillna(0)
```

Result:

```
                    revenue
model   day                
polo    2006-01-01     0.00
        2006-02-01   293.15
        2006-03-01   458.87
sweater 2006-01-01     0.00
        2006-02-01   143.14
```

Comment: actually, almost: the result frame doesn't seem to still have a `model` column. Any quick fix to restore it? (Better than concatenating the column from `tmp`)

Comment: Also, it doesn't seem to be actually working: days 0-59 all show rolling sum 0, while day 60 (and onwards) shows the sum incuding themselves

Comment: already found it needs `,min_periods=1` to work, but `closed='right'` just doesn't seem to do anything. May have to simply subtract the original column from this.